# Get instagram username from URL - ignore periods with regex

Tags: php, regex

I've been able to retrieve the Username from an instagram profile URL with regex, however it stops once it reaches a full-stop

> .

Full URL:
https://www.instagram.com/username.test.uk/

The output from my regex:
https://www.instagram.com/username

My regex and output:

```
// Regex for verifying an instagram URL
$regex = '/(?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www.)?(?:instagram.com|instagr.am)\/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/im';

// Verify valid Instagram URL
if ( preg_match( $regex, $instagram_url, $matches ) ) {

    $instagram_username = $matches[1];

    var_dump($instagram_username);
```

The var dump produces: **username**

Any obvious changes needed to my regex to exclude . in the username section?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So it stops because your match for the username doesn't include the `.`.

```
/(?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www.)?(?:instagram.com|instagr.am)\/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/im
```

This should probably include `\.` within `([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)`. You also should escape the `.` elsewhere in your regex so it matches only the `.` character instead of anything.

```
/(?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:instagram\.com|instagr\.am)\/([A-Za-z0-9-_\.]+)/im
```

This will capture all alpha-numerics, underscores and dots.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Will accept in a few minutes when it allows.

Comment: A slight optional improvement would be to drop `A-Z` as you have the `i` flag (meaning case-insensitive) meaning `A-Z` is the same as `a-z`. I am not sure what other characters are allowed in a username on instagram but I can imagine at some point you will find more, in this case you just add more to the group. A note, special characters and symbols (often) require escaping `\` before the character, hence `\.` because `.` in regex means any character.

Comment: @MatthewUsurp you missed on one corner case where username is all alphabet. Eg
`https://www.instagram.com/homedesign/?hl=en`

Answer (score 0):

For link that is generated by app 'nametag option'

```html
https?:\/\/www\.?instagram\.com\/([A-Za-z0-9_](?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]|(?:\.(?!\.))){0,28}(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]))?\S)\?r=nametag
```